# StandardOutput blocks when asked for user input

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently building a simple application, and it starts `openvpn.exe`. However, `openvpn.exe` asks for an username and password.

**But**, when this happens, my program does not read the string, it simply waits until the CMD is closed and then continues on with the code. So, it blocks until the window is closed.

Is there any way to circumvent this? My code is as follows:

```
void button_Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var proc = new Process();


    proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "--config config.ovpn --auto-proxy";
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin";

    // set up output redirection
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    // Input
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    // Other
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    // see below for output handler
    proc.ErrorDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;
    proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;

    proc.Start();

    myStreamWriter = proc.StandardInput;
    proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

    proc.WaitForExit();
}

void proc_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // output will be in string e.Data
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        string Data = e.Data.ToString();
        if (Data.Contains("Enter Auth Username"))
        {
            this.myStreamWriter.WriteLine("myinput");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been fighting with the same problem, and unfortunately you'll never be able to fully control any process like that. The problem is, last line of the output is somehow never visible by the Process class. Can you find any .net API for this VPN? I think that would be a lot better approach.

Comment: I would try to do the same think with a command line application that you wrote (to be sure your code is correct).

Comment: @Ikaso funny thing to notice is, if the console would say "Enter Auth Username" and displayed the prompt in the new line, then the above code would work.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `proc_DataReceived` is triggered on **new line**. Assuming the password is the only input that console app is asking for, you can just send it to your `myStreamWriter` right after starting the process. It will be buffered and consumed when necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's asking more than that. I'd really like to be able to read it. It works with AutoIT though (as in that doesn't block).

Comment: @Devator assuming reads always occur in the same order, you can `WriteLine()` them into the buffer in the same order and it will work. If you want truly interactive approach, then you have to implement your own stdout buffer. Create a background thread and `buffer.Write(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd())` in a loop there. Then examine the content of the buffer.

Comment: I only need 2 WriteLines, first one for user and second for password. When doing both after eachother, only the username works. It's posting the password too fast. Now I can do dirty and put a sleep for 5 seconds, but that's simply not nice. Is there any other solution?